# How to fix Selenium unable to find element error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am having issues locating an element with selenium in my python script and I cannot figure out why it is unable to locate the element in this [webpage](https://permits.mynevadacounty.com/CitizenAccess/Cap/CapHome.aspx?module=Building&TabName=Building). I tried two approaches one regular and another that waits for the page to load and neither worked with the first displaying this error : "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="btnGSExpandCollapse"]"}" and the asynchronous approach simply timing out. Here is the code

first approach:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://permits.mynevadacounty.com/CitizenAccess/Cap/CapHome.aspx?module=Building&TabName=Building")
expand_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnGSExpandCollapse")
expand_button.click()
```

second approach:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://permits.mynevadacounty.com/CitizenAccess/Cap/CapHome.aspx?module=Building&TabName=Building")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "btnGSExpandCollapse"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are looking for doesn't actually exist on the page until AFTER you click the "Search Additional Critera" link. What you are looking for when the page first loads is

```
<span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_lblGSLoadASI">Search Additional Criteria</span>
```

which can be located by its ID,

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_lblGSLoadASI"))).click()
```

NOTE: When you are waiting for an element that you are going to click, use `EC.element_to_be_clickable()`. If you are going to interact with an element, e.g. `.text`, etc. then use `EC.visibility_of_element_located()`. Presence just means that the element is in the DOM, not that it's interactable. You might get lucky most of the time but there's a chance that if you wait for present and then interact with or click an element you'll get an error. It happens more on pages that load slowly.

---

The working code looks like

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://permits.mynevadacounty.com/CitizenAccess/Cap/CapHome.aspx?module=Building&TabName=Building")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[src='/CitizenAccess/nc-horizontal.png']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_lblGSLoadASI"))).click()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried this code out but i can't actually tell if it's working, what would be a good way to confirm? when the browser pops up I don't see the expanded section appearing

Comment: @jim The problem is that the site is poorly designed. The initial page comes in fairly quickly but the link isn't clickable at that point. The header with images comes in after several seconds and then the page is usable. I updated my answer to include the full code to get everything working. I ended up waiting for the header image to be visible before waiting for the link and clicking it and it's working.

Comment: this works thank you! sorry fo the late response!